# Create new section and take time difference if time exceeds a certain amount (R, Dplyr)

Tags: r, dplyr, difftime

I have a dataset, df, that has 10,000 rows:

```
DateA

9/9/2019 7:52:16 PM
9/9/2019 7:52:16 PM
9/9/2019 7:52:17 PM
9/9/2019 7:52:18 PM
9/9/2019 7:52:18 PM
9/9/2019 7:52:19 PM
9/10/2019 1:02:23 AM
9/10/2019 1:02:25 AM
9/10/2019 1:02:26 AM
9/10/2019 1:02:27 AM
9/10/2019 1:02:27 AM
9/10/2019 1:02:29 AM
9/10/2019 1:02:29 AM
9/10/2019 1:03:29 AM    
9/10/2019 1:03:29 AM    
9/10/2019 1:03:31 AM    
9/10/2019 1:03:32 AM    
9/10/2019 4:18:48 AM    
9/10/2019 4:18:50 AM    
9/10/2019 4:18:51 AM
```

I would like this output:

```
Group   Duration

 a       3 sec
 b       6 sec
 c       3 sec
 d       3 sec
```

I would like the  thresh to be set to 1 min or 60 sec. If a lapse of more than 60 seconds is detected, a new group will be made, along with its duration.

dput:

```
 structure(list(DateA = structure(c(12L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 14L,   15L, 
 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L),      .Label = c("9/10/2019 1:02:23 AM", 
"9/10/2019 1:02:25 AM", "9/10/2019 1:02:26 AM", "9/10/2019   1:02:27 AM", 
"9/10/2019 1:02:29 AM", "9/10/2019 1:03:29 AM", "9/10/2019 1:03:31 AM", 
"9/10/2019 1:03:32 AM", "9/10/2019 4:18:48 AM", "9/10/2019 4:18:50 AM", 
"9/10/2019 4:18:51 AM", "9/9/2019 7:52:16 PM", "9/9/2019 7:52:17 PM", 
"9/9/2019 7:52:18 PM", "9/9/2019 7:52:19 PM"), class =  "factor")), class =   "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
 -20L))
```

I have tried:

```
 thresh1 <-60

 library(data.table)
 setDT(df)[, DateA := as.ITime(as.character(DateA))][, 
  .(Duration = difftime(max(as.POSIXct(DateA)),         min(as.POSIXct(DateA)), 
   unit = 'sec')),.(group = letters[cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(DateA) >     thresh1))])]
```

However, I am doing something wrong because I am only getting the output of 1 row.

```
  group  Duration

   a       0
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong? Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Are you checking lapse with only previous row?

Comment: I just wish to group and find duration, given the timelapse does not exceed 60 secs. So all 7:52 datetime will be grouped, and 1:02 will be grouped...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can convert `DateA` to `POSIXct` class, `format` it to include information only till minute precision and find the difference between `max` and `min` duration in each group.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(DateA = lubridate::dmy_hms(DateA), 
         temp = format(DateA, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")) %>%
  group_by(temp) %>%
  summarise(duration = difftime(max(DateA), min(DateA), units = "secs"))

# A tibble: 4 x 2
#  temp             duration
#  <chr>            <drtn>  
#1 2019-09-09 19:52 3 secs  
#2 2019-10-09 01:02 6 secs  
#3 2019-10-09 01:03 3 secs  
#4 2019-10-09 04:18 3 secs
```

Comment: Ok I will try @Ronak Is there a way to add a thresh? If the timelapse is greater than 1 min?

Comment: @TanishaHudson Since you want to include all the minute information together, I use `temp` to store data only till minutes which also avoids using `thresh`.

Comment: Ok so essentially it will create a new group when the next timestamp is over 60 seconds?  1:00:01 1:02:00  These would be in two separate groups?

Comment: Yes and also `1:00:59` and `1:01:01` would be in separate groups.

Comment: ok I just tried on my dataset that has over 4000  rows , and it says 3075 failed to parse. They are all in the same datetime format: 9/12/2019 8:22:36 PM

Comment: It isn't clear from your sample if your date format is `dmy` or `mdy`. Use `lubridate::mdy_hms(DateA)`

Comment: Furthermore @Ronak, If I wanted to add a thresh of 2 or 5 minutes, how would I incorporate this in this code? state the thresh and then place it where?

Comment: You can use `floor_date` or `ceiling_date` function from `lubridate`. Replace the `temp` line with `temp = floor_date(DateA, "2 mins"))` or `temp = floor_date(DateA, "5mins"))`

Comment: will the floor_date / ceiling_date avoid this?  "also 1:00:59 and 1:01:01 would be in separate groups"  How do I avoid the 1:00:59 and 1:01:01 being in separate groups?

Comment: yes, it will avoid it if you round it to anything greater than 1 mins.